# What's the this value in callback arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, callback, this, arrow-functions, executioncontext

So as I am reading on the execution context in javascript and how does it works, everything seemed fine until I tried some examples on the this value of callback arrow functions.

```js
const printCard = function () {
  this.signatories.forEach((signatory) =>
    console.log(this) /* expected to return signatories, returned messageConfig */
  );
};

const messageConfig = {
  closing: {
    Thor: "Admiration, respect, and love",
    Loki: "Your son",
  },
  signatories: ["Thor", "Loki"],
};

printCard.call(messageConfig);
```

Here since forEach is prototypal method of signatories, I expected the callback (the arrow function) to automatically take the this value from the enclosing context (forEach in this case). However, it seemed to return the messageConfig which reminds me of lexical scoping a little bit.

Comment: The "enclosing context" is the function (with the keyword) function you've made, which has the "enclosing context" of being `messageConfig` in this case

Comment: `the enclosing context` is not what you think it is - add `console.log(this);` before the `forEach` ... that's the `this` for the arrow function

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't pass a `this` context when it calls its function. And even if it did, arrow functions ignore the context that's passed to them, they  bind the context from the scope where they're defined.

Comment: So `this` in the arrow function is the same as `this` in `printCard`.

Comment: The third argument passed to the `forEach()` callback function is the array that's being iterated. So `forEach((signatory, i, signatories) => ...)`

Comment: "*What's the `this` value in callback arrow functions?*" - the same as the `this` value in arrow functions that are not used as callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.forEach()` doesn't pass the array as the `this` context to its callback function. It passes the array it's looping over as the third argument. So if you want to get signatories, use

```
const printCard = function () {
  this.signatories.forEach((signatory, i, signatories) =>
    console.log(signatories);
  );
};
```

You can optionally pass a second argument to `forEach()` and this will be passed as the `this` context.

However, arrow functions don't accept a passed `this` context, so that wouldn't help here. They inherit the context from the defining scope. Since you're binding the context to `messageConfig` when you use `printCard.call()`, that's the value of `this` in `printCard()` and also the callback function.

If you were to change the callback function to a regular function, `this` would be the `window` object in a browser, or the `global` object in node.js, unless the code is in strict mode.

Comment: While it is true that `.forEach()` passes the array being iterated over as the third argument to the callback, it also [accepts a second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters) to be used as `this` inside that callback.

Comment: Completely forgot about that feature (even more obscure than the third argument to the cb). I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function just borrows `this` and `arguments` from the outer scope (it doesn't have own). The outer scope is `printCard()` which is called with `this = messageConfig`, and arguments `arg1` and `arg2`. You can access the array with `this.signatories` or use the third argument of `forEach()` which is the array of being iterated.

Arrow functions are useful as callbacks inside methods since you have `this` inside them as an instance a method is called on, so no need in bind/call/apply/self as with a usual `function`.

```js
const printCard = function () {
  this.signatories.forEach((signatory, i, arr) => {
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log(this.signatories);
    console.log(arr);
  });
};

const messageConfig = {
  closing: {
    Thor: "Admiration, respect, and love",
    Loki: "Your son",
  },
  signatories: ["Thor", "Loki"],
};

printCard.call(messageConfig, 'arg1', 'arg2');
```